# Como centralizar uma janela na outra no GTK?

Tags: c, gtk

Tenho uma janela principal e desejo exibir pequenos textos em uma janela pequena, aberta no centro da janela principal. Ainda não consegui fazer com que a janela pequena abra no centro da principal.

Tentei utilizar `GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL` e `GTK_WINDOW_POPUP` juntamente com as funções `gtk_widget_set_parent_window` e `gtk_widget_set_parent`, porém não produziram o efeito desejado. Ao utilizar `gtk_widget_set_parent_window`, a janela com o aviso não é exibida.

O código atual para abri-la:

```
static void show_warning(char *title, char *text)
{
    GtkWidget *warning_window;
    GtkWidget *box;
    GtkWidget *label;
    GtkWidget *button;

    warning_window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(warning_window), title);
    g_signal_connect(GTK_WINDOW(warning_window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_widget_destroy), NULL);
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(warning_window), 20);
    gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(warning_window), FALSE);    

    //window é a janela principal
    gtk_widget_set_parent(warning_window, window);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(warning_window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER_ON_PARENT);

    box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 10);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(warning_window), box);

    label = gtk_label_new(text);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), label, TRUE, FALSE, 0);

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Ok");
    g_signal_connect_swapped(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(gtk_widget_destroy), warning_window);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), button, TRUE, FALSE, 0);

    gtk_widget_show_all(warning_window);    
}
```

**Como fazer com que a janela com aviso abra no centro da janela principal?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui criar a janela como queria utilizando uma solução mais simples.

```
static void show_warning(char *title, char *text)
{
    GtkWidget *warning_dialog;
    GtkWidget *content_area;
    GtkWidget *label;

    warning_dialog = gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons
                                    (   title,
                                        GTK_WINDOW(window),
                                        GTK_DIALOG_MODAL,
                                        "Ok",
                                        GTK_RESPONSE_NONE,
                                        NULL                    );

    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(warning_dialog), 10);
    gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(warning_dialog), FALSE);

    content_area = gtk_dialog_get_content_area(GTK_DIALOG(warning_dialog));
    label = gtk_label_new(text);

    g_signal_connect_swapped(   warning_dialog, 
                                "response", 
                                G_CALLBACK(gtk_widget_destroy), 
                                warning_dialog                  );

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(content_area), label);
    gtk_widget_show_all(warning_dialog);
}
```